# where/how to find the last linux-image patched with apparmor (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)

Tags: kernel, patch, apparmor

where/how to find the last linux-image patched with apparmor (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
without patvhing myself the kernel?
thanks

answer: 
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/linux-image
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/linux-headers-3.2.0-24
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic-pae/3.2.0-24.39

Answer (score 0):

You can see the history of the Precise (3.2) linux kernel at http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=ubuntu/ubuntu-precise.git;a=log. It took a few seconds for it to come up for me.

There's a wiki containing information about the Ubuntu kernel team [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/).

Wikipedia says that apparmor has been included in the kernel for quite some time, by the way.